# error when launching the Flutter project via Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I run my application on Flutter via Xcode on a physical iPhone and encounter the error "Module 'module_name' not found" in the GeneratedPluginRegistrant file. If you run it through Flutter itself, then everything starts well. What could be the problem? And I need to run it through Xcode so that there would be logs specifically for iOS.
Maybe someone has encountered this error?

[image]